# How to read two rows and two columns of a pandas dataframe at once and apply conditions on those rows/column values?

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement, dataframe, conditional-statements

I want to read two rows and two columns at once in a pandas Dataframe and then apply condition dependent `zip vs. product` of the strings between two rows/columns matrix of `pandas Dataframe`.

```
import pandas as pd
import itertools as it
from itertools import product

cond_mcve = pd.read_csv('condition01.mcve.txt', sep='\t')

  alfa  alfa_index beta  beta_index delta  delta_index
0  a,b          23  c,d          36   a,c           32
1  a,c          23  b,e          37   c,d           32
2  g,h          28  d,f          37   e,g           32
3  a,b          28  c,d          39   a,c           34
4  c,e          28  b,g          39   d,k           34
```

- Here **alfa, beta and delta** are strings values and they have their own corresponding indexes.
- I want to create the `zip` of two adjacent strings (by rows) if they have the same index values. **So, for the first two lines for `alfa column` the output should be `aa,cb` since the `alfa_index` for both lines is 23**.
- But, for the 2nd and 3rd line of alfa column the two indexes value differ (23 and 28) so, the output should be a product of the strings i.e **output: ga,gc,ha,hc**

**This is what I have mentally thought about doing do:**
And, I hope that I am explaining the problem very clearly.

```
# write a function
def some_function():
    read_two columns at once (based on prefix similarity)

    then:
    if two integer_index are same:
        zip(of strings belonging to that index)

    if two integer index are different:
        product(of strings belonging to that index)

# take this function and apply it to pandas dataframe:
cond_mcve_updated = cond_mcve+cond_mcve.shift(1).dropna(how='all').applymap(some_function)
```

Here `shift` is able to read two lines at a time, so my problem of reading two rows at one time is solved. **But, I am having other problems while reading two columns and implementation of the condition:**

- reading two column at once in pandas dataframe (based on prefix similarity).
- separating these columns to compare index values(integer)
- apply zip vs. product based on the condition

The expected final output will be:

```
   alfa          alfa_index    beta             beta_index    delta  delta_index
1  aa,cb         23            bc,bd,ec,ed      37            ca,dc           32
2  ga,gc,ha,hc   28            db,fe            37            ec,gd           32
same for other line.....

# the first index(i.e 0 is lost) but that's ok. I can work it out using `head/tail` method in pandas.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to achieve the result.  This function uses `shift`, `concat`, and `apply` to run the data into a function which can do the prod/sum thing based on matching `_index` values.

**Code:**

```
import itertools as it

def crazy_prod_sum_thing(frame):
    # get the labels which do not end with _index
    labels = [(l, l + '_index')
              for l in frame.columns.values if not l.endswith('_index')]

    def func(row):
        # get row n and row n-1
        front = row[:len(row) >> 1]
        back = row[len(row) >> 1:]

        # loop through the labels
        results = []
        for l, i in labels:
            x = front[l].split(',')
            y = back[l].split(',')
            if front[i] == back[i]:
                results.append(x[0] + y[0] + ',' + x[1] + x[1])
            else:
                results.append(
                    ','.join([x1 + y1 for x1, y1 in it.product(x, y)]))

        return pd.Series(results)

    # take this function and apply it to pandas dataframe:
    df = pd.concat([frame, frame.shift(1)], axis=1)[1:].apply(
        func, axis=1)

    df.rename(columns={i: x[0] + '_cpst' for i, x in enumerate(labels)},
              inplace=True)
    return pd.concat([frame, df], axis=1)
```

**Test Code:**

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
data = [x.strip() for x in """
      alfa  alfa_index beta  beta_index delta  delta_index
    0  a,b          23  c,d          36   a,c           32
    1  a,c          23  b,e          37   c,d           32
    2  g,h          28  d,f          37   e,g           32
    3  a,b          28  c,d          39   a,c           34
    4  c,e          28  b,g          39   d,k           34
""".split('\n')[1:-1]]
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(u'\n'.join(data)), sep='\s+')
print(df)

print(crazy_prod_sum_thing(df))
```

**Results:**

```
  alfa  alfa_index beta  beta_index delta  delta_index
0  a,b          23  c,d          36   a,c           32
1  a,c          23  b,e          37   c,d           32
2  g,h          28  d,f          37   e,g           32
3  a,b          28  c,d          39   a,c           34
4  c,e          28  b,g          39   d,k           34

1          [aa,cc, bc,bd,ec,ed, ca,dd]
2          [ga,gc,ha,hc, db,ff, ec,gg]
3    [ag,bb, cd,cf,dd,df, ae,ag,ce,cg]
4                [ca,ee, bc,gg, da,kk]
```

**Note:**

This does not marshal the result back into a dataframe as indicated in the question, because I was not sure how to take the index values when they did not match.

Comment: This must be something workable. I will try to workout if there is a way to retain back the index values. Thanks much. I am not fully accepting the answer yet but will, at the meantime hoping some other answers may be added too just for my knowledge. Waiting couple of days to get some attention on this problem. Thanks.

Comment: I just tried the code but it ran into the error during `print(crazy_prod_sum_thing(df))` **Error msg:** `TypeError: ("cannot do slice indexing on <class 'pandas.indexes.base.Index'> with these indexers [6.0] of <class 'float'>", 'occurred at index 1')` It suggests something about the `float` but the index values are supposed to be integers. What might be the problem?

Comment: Tried with both.  I also printed the output of the file you created and what I had posted. Both are exactly the same and same type. Both are giving exactly same error messages. idk why?

Comment: let me check that quickly. Also, what does `indexers [6.0]` mean. There is no such value.

Comment: `import pandas as pd
print(pd.__version__)
0.19.0` Its the latest version. Let me update it quickly to `0.19.2` and report back to you.

Comment: Sorry, no changes. Any suggestions.

Comment: I hope not to bother you too much. But, do you think if something else might be causing the problem. Thanks !

Comment: Let me go ahead and try. Thanks for being of so much help. Also, to add. I think the index values can be brought back if we can merge the `output df` with the `input df` except at the `index[0]`.

Comment: I can bring it back by naming the `columns` specifically, but I wanted to embed a `for-loop` so it works out the issue no matter how many columns are there with whatever name (but matching prefix). I will go ahead and try, else it will be a different question. But, thanks much again for the code.

Comment: Would you be able to spare a few minutes to do a brief discussion in this question. I am having a minor problem and tried to fix it by going over pandas documentation, but not able to set a fix. I rather have a quick discussion rather than post another lengthy question. Let me know, just a simple `yes or no` would suffice. I totally understand if you can't. Thanks

Comment: Sure we can start a chatroom

Comment: I think I don't have a privilege to start a chat room. Can you invite me in one?

Comment: I think I found it. Please knock on : http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138491/everestial007

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138492/discussion-between-everestial007-and-stephen-rauch).

Comment: I am in the chat room. Thanks,

Comment: I just put the issue on chatroom. Its a simple one but I don't find a way of fixing it. Could you please have a look? thanks,